# Setting global python version with pyenv is not working as expected

Tags: python, pyenv

Regarding pyenv:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

I have this:

```
$ pyenv global 2.7
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

My pyenv version is:

```
pyenv 1.2.2
```

does anyone know the right way to set a python version for any particular shell (and child shells)?

Comment: If I am not very mistaken you can just do `pyenv shell X.X`

Comment: @patrick, I get `pyenv: no such command `shell'`

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell) the `shell` command should be a thing. But note *Note that you'll need pyenv's shell integration enabled (step 3 of the [installation instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)) in order to use this command.* Looks like that just requires adding pyenv init to your shell

Comment: Can you post the output of the command `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 9):

Just to elaborate on my comment, now that I have some time.

The [docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-shell) describe the `shell` command for this purpose, which you can run like so:

`pyenv shell pypy-2.2.1`

#### Notes:

If you installed pyenv via Homebrew et al, that should work out of the box (it did for me). If not, the [installation instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) detail a necessary step:

> Add pyenv init to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion. Please make sure eval "$(pyenv init -)" is placed toward the end of the shell configuration file since it manipulates PATH during the initialization.

The specific command they suggest (for bash) is:

`$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Then restart the shell.

There is some further caveats for specific shells listed on the installation instructions linked. Hope this helps.

Comment: for zsh can we change .bash_profile to zsh_profile or zshrc ? any more changes needed here ?

Answer (score -1):

For MacOS I had to set the global version `pyenv global 3.10.1` and then `exec $SHELL`